# Specific fluid sim look

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I've spent the past couple months trying to figure out some fluid sim for a project. I'm trying to go for a specific (and slightly unrealistic) water flow look:

[image: fluid sim goal]

However, I don't seem to be able to get anything that looks like this. I've spent the last month(s) frustrated at this. The best I was able to get is:

[image: best fluid sim so far]

and even then, there's still a bunch of splashes and other undesirable parts. I'm beginning to wonder if a fluid simulation is the best option, but I don't know what else would work. A bare-bones blend file of what I have so far is included below (not including the baked data, I don't think)
I've tried guides, wind, and messed around with a lot of other settings, to no avail.

(Note: my goal is to make the water look photo-realistic, and hopefully animated if possible)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Position the inflow as desired. In an Inflow section set X **and** Z to non-zero values(Z to -1) and see if it works.
[image]

Comment: when I do that, the inflow becomes kinda stepped (https://imgur.com/DyHfFPC), and the splashing at the bottom pipe is still there.